# Google Maps v3, polyline mouse events

Tags: events, google-maps, polyline

Is it possible to detect when the mouse has entered and exited a polyline region in Google Maps v3?

As a particular use-case, I would like to change the color of a polyline when then mouse is hovering over it. Polylines allow registration of a "mousemove" event, but it doesn't seem to allow notification of mouse over/out events. This strikes me as a pretty basic bit of utility. Are there any solutions for doing this sort of thing? Is this an inappropriate use of polylines?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps team has added a mouseover event for polylines as of Apr 26, 2010 (Google Maps Javascript API V3).